# How to check a variable is within a range for a period of time

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements, timeout

I have some code which will check the current temperature against a target and keep checking until that target temperature has been reached and a timeout threshold has not been exceeded. What I would like to do is have a means of checking that the current temperature stays within tolerance for a certain amount of time, i.e. for a minute or two, then the loop would stop.

What I have is:

**Code**

```
import time

timeout_mins = 7
time_now = time.time()
timeout = time.time() + (timeout_mins * 60)

tolerance = 1
# current_temp is a float output in real time by a temperature sensor. target_temperature is a user settable float.
while abs(current_temp - target_temperature) > tolerance and time_now  < timeout:
    degree_sign = u"\N{DEGREE SIGN}" 
    current_temp = my_sys.Temperature
    temp_display = "{:.2f}".format(current_temp)
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print(f"System temperature = {temp_display}" + degree_sign + "C" + "  Time = " + current_time)

timeout2 = time.time() + 120
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
while abs(current_temp - target_temperature) < tolerance and time_now  < timeout2:
    print("less than tolerance : " + current_time) 
    time.sleep(check_time)
```

This will get the system to temperature, but once it reaches temperature and the timeout is finished there is a good chance the temperature will fluctuate until equilibrium is achieved, what im looking for is an equilibrium check.

Comment: What is current_temp

Comment: the current temperature, a float coming from a temperature sensor. Target temperature is also a float.

Comment: Seems like all you need to do is have another while loop that watches the current temperature and makes sure it stays within the tolerance for however long the time period is you want to consider as "stable".

Comment: @martineau yes, but im not sure how to do it, I have updated question with my second while loop, I have to wait and see if it works as there is a lag.

Comment: Well, let us know. Note, esp for doing initial alpha-testing couldn't the time period be shortened to expedite things?

Comment: yes, luckily the first while loop stops as soon as it reaches target. I have also speeded it up by smaller temperature increases. One more issue and I'll bring some feedback.